# ASP.NET how to set a variable in web.config during publising an app

Tags: asp.net, variables, deployment, web-config, environment

I have an ASP.NET application and I would like to set a variable during publishing the application depending on the environment (like production, quality, etc....)
I have created a variable in the web.config file in the `<appSettings />` section inside `<configuration />` section like this:

```
<add key="RunningEnvironment" value="dev"/>
```

I have two profiles when deploying dev and prod

How can I set the RunningEnvironment variable in the web.config depending on the profile I choose when deploying?

Comment: You should take a look to "web.config transformation". You can define a web.config for each compilation target: debug, release or whatever you defined. Here is the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx  or here  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [web.config transformations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations).

In your `Web.Production.Config` for production environment set this:

```
<add xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" key="RunningEnvironment" value="prod"/>
```

A handy tip you better know is *Preview Transform* dropdown menu option on `Web.<ConfigurationName>.Config` file in Visual Studio. There you will see all the changes that are going to take effect.

Comment: I have created a Web.production.Config file as well as a Web.Dev.Config file. When I deploy my site, both files are deployed. How do I choose the correct one in the deploying process ?

Comment: @John Smith, see [how it should look like](http://i.imgur.com/gHLbU5j.png). Also try right-clicking you `Web.Config` and look for something like `Add Config Transform`.

Comment: @John Smith, important fact is that in `Web.Name.Config` - `Name` should correspond to you configuration name. When you do publish you select configuration.

Comment: I found out that my application has two pubxml files, one for the production and one for dev. How do I add one entry in each file to set my RunningEnvironment variable to prod or dev ?

Comment: @John Smith, Ok. You have several configurations for the project, by default they are Debug and Release. There are Web.Debug.Config and Web.Release.Config files by default as well. In you pubxml files there should be a line `<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>ConfigName</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>`. When you click `publish` on you project a windows will be opened. Go to **settings** tab, select corresponding configuration.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, my  LastUsedBuildConfiguration item was called Release and that's what confused me.

Comment: One thing that is important and I didn't know when adding a transform element in a web.dev.config file is that the path must match the path of the Web.Config file  i.e. I was missing the appSettings tags e.g. <appSettings>
    <add key="RunningEnvironment" value="dev" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>